# How to fit a large image in image view without rotating it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

My image size is 2000x1900 and my image view size is 500x500.When I set the image in the image view its rotate the image.I also used

```
contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Check image orientation.It is UIImageOrientationUp.But still I get the rotate image.So any one help me what is the reason and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Setting the image in the imageView should not rotate the image by itself. How are you adding the image? What is its source? Are you using Core Image filters or something else that is modifying the image data?

Answer (score 1):

it may be help for you..

If I understand, what you want to do is disregard the orientation of the UIImage? If so then you could do this:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [... whatever ...];

UIImage *imageToDisplay =
     [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
              scale:1.0
              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below method to resize your image

```
-(UIImage *)compressImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    float actualHeight = image.size.height;
    float actualWidth = image.size.width;
    float maxHeight = 500;
    float maxWidth = 500;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth/maxHeight;
    float compressionQuality = 1;//50 percent compression

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth){
        if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
            //adjust width according to maxHeight
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
        }
        else if(imgRatio > maxRatio){
            //adjust height according to maxWidth
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
        else{
            actualHeight = maxHeight;
            actualWidth = maxWidth;
        }
    }
    actualHeight = 2000;
    actualWidth = 1900;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compressionQuality);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

In above method set height-width as per your requirement.
Hope it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for fix orientation issue.

**UIImage+fixOrientation.h**

```
@interface UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;

@end
```

**UIImage+fixOrientation.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}

@end
```

Use as

```
#import "UIImage+fixOrientation.h"

UIImage *image = [yourImage fixOrientation];
yourImageView.image = image;
```